# Visual Studio Set-up Project

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I have created a set-up project for my solution.  I have a new assembly version and have flagged it to remove previous versions.  However, when I distribute the software, if a machine currently has a previous version installed it simply brings up a message saying they should manually remove any other versions.

If I change the remove previous versions to false then the new program doesn't appear to install correctly (although no error is displayed).  I've tried changing the ProductCode and that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone tell me what the required steps are to upgrade a currently installed piece of software are (or point me to a place that does) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work you need to do three steps:

Select in the Solution Explorer your Setup project. Now open the *View - Properties Window* (**not** right click Properties).

- Set **RemovePreviousVersion** to **true**
- Increase the **Version** in any place (e.g. from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1)
- Select **Yes** in the upcoming dialog about changing the product code